# Is calculating the metric tensor circular logic?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

The Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor, and the Ricci scalar begin as a function of the metric tensor.

However, in the Schwarzschild solution the coefficients for that metric are found by solving the Einstein field equations.

Which themselves are composed of the Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor, and the Ricci scalar and again are a function of the metric.

So isn't that a bit circular?

How can you find the metric to solve the field equations to find the metric?

Comment: One usually begins with assumptions about the spacetime (e.g. in the Schwarzschild case, spherical symmetry) and/or matter content. And then you go ahead and look at the EFE, from which you *derive* the Schwarzschild solution.

Comment: Think of the differential equation $f''(x)+\lambda f(x)=0$. Now consider defining one object $G_f(x) = f''(x)+\lambda f(x)$. The equation $G_f = 0$ is the same equation as before. Would you say there's something circular here? Point is, the Ricci tensor is indeed a functional of the metric and the Einstein tensor is built from it and the metric. In the end of the day if you expanded everything out you would have a giant left hand side just involving the metric set equal to zero.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment and the other answer by d_b: in GR we almost never just start with a completely arbitrary metric. We usually make assumptions about the spacetime (e.g. in the Schwarzschild case, spherical symmetry), and/or the matter content $T_{\mu \nu}$. And then you go ahead and look at the EFE, from which you *derive* the Schwarzschild solution.

The assumptions we make about $g_{\mu \nu}$ are based on physical reasons, e.g. we want to describe spacetime filled with a uniform isotropic fluid, or the spacetime around a spherically symmetric mass, etc. But this still leaves free functions in the metric for which we need to use the field equations to solve for. So it obviously must be the case that the EFE are functions of the metric (the dynamical field of the theory).

Answer (score 2):

In Newtonian mechanics, the force is a function of the position of a particle. But the solution for the position is found by solving Newton's second law, which itself depends on the force. So how can we find the position? Well, we write down the force in terms of the unknown position and end up with a differential equation to solve for the position.

It is exactly the same in general relativity. We write down the Einstein equations in terms of the unknown metric, and we end up with a differential equation we can (hopefully!) solve to find the metric.

Comment: Then do all created metrics that describe spacetime have to conform to the Einstein field equations? I word it that way because what if a metric was invented that used coefficients that were not derived using the Einstein field equations but accurately describes spacetime in extreme environments, such as near black holes and still reduces to flat Minkowski spacetime infinitely far away. Yet the coefficients were not born from the field equations and could not and this metric still forms an accurate spacetime interval. Would such a metric still be valid?

Comment: @PythonHouse Physical spacetimes (in our current best theory of gravity, which is general relativity) are those with metrics that obey the Einstein equations, full stop. The metric doesn't necessarily have to be "derived" using the field equations — in theory it could have been guessed at by other means — but it must satisfy them.

Comment: @PythonHouse I also point out that metrics for spacetimes containing black holes (e.g., Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics) *are* derived from the Einstein equations anyway.

Comment: "Physical spacetimes (in our current best theory of gravity, which is general relativity) are those with metrics that obey the Einstein equations, full stop". How can that be when we know that General Relativity isn't the final theory on gravity? So by that very reasoning there must exist metrics that don't satisfy GR but will satisfy some another theory that has gone beyond GR. For example GR deals with geometry but by its nature any theory of "quantum gravity probably will not. It seems pretty myopic to say - "full stop" when we don't know.

Comment: @PythonHouse We don't know what future theories of gravity will look like, but we do know that they must reproduce the results of general relativity in the appropriate limit(s), because GR has been successful in predicting the observed behavior of gravity in our universe. In the same way, we demand that quantum mechanics reproduce the results of classical mechanics, or that general relativity reproduce the results of Newtonian gravity. Einstein knew that the minimal requirement of any new theory is that it agrees with the old theory when their range of validity overlaps.

Comment: @PythonHouse That is why he almost gave up on general relativity at one point, believing that it did not reproduce Newtonian gravity, as you can read about here: https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-einstein-lost-his-bearings-and-with-them-general-relativity-20180314/ Similarly, any researcher in quantum gravity knows that their theory must at the very least give us back Einstein's equations in the regime in which they apply.